# EPPLUS - How can I change chartarea height?

Tags: excel, charts, epplus

I'd like to change the chartarea height, but I cannot find where the property is.

[image]

I also tried to find it through ChartXML, but I cannot find it..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `SetSize` method. Note that there are 2 overloads, one that takes % and one that takes pixel size.

```c#
using (var ep = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    var chart = ws.Drawings[0];
    //Or, to create a new one:
    //var chart = ws.Drawings.AddChart("mychart", OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartType.XYScatter);
    //Set the size in pixels:
    chart.SetSize(200, 300);
    ep.SaveAs(file2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I was looking for was not SetSize, but I guess SetSize and that height are somehow related. I wanted to use that specific number. but I might be able to use SetSize instead.